# .chosen.change() - how to figure out whether it was a select or a deselect action

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

How can we figure out whether a change event triggered on a component was a result of a select or a deselect? 
How can we grab the value of the selected value only or the deselected value only?

```
$("#airports-select-2").chosen().change(function(event) {
    console.log('select2 change', event, $(event.target).val());
});
```

This code gives me all the values that have been selected so far on a multiselect component? How can this be changed to only give me value of the newly selected or deselected component?

Comment: If the Chosen plugin can't give you that information in the callback, you'll probably have to save the list of selected items in an array and then compare and update that array each time the `change` callback is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every event fire you can trigger:

```
var  target = $(event.target),
     priorDataSet = target.data("chosen-values"),
     currentDataSet = target.val();

//Diff and compare the delta here.    

target.data("chosen-values", currentDataSet);
```

Prior to the update of the data for the DOM element you can diff to determine what the delta is between the value sets.  If it's in the old and not in the new it's removed.  If it's in the new and not in the old then it's been added.

If you need an example of how to determine the delta between two arrays let me know and I'll whip up an example for that as well.

Answer (score 42):

From Chosen [documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html):

> Chosen triggers the standard DOM event whenever a selection is made
>   (it also sends a ***selected*** or ***deselected*** parameter that tells you which
>   option was changed).

```
  $('select').on('change', function(event, params) {
    // can now use params.selected and params.deselected
  });
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to cancel a change event? suppose User selects and option and a change event is fired, but based on some condition i want to revert this selection.

Comment: You could revert <select> values to a previous state and then trigger chosen:updated : $('select').val([1,2,3]).trigger('chosen:updated');

Comment: Hmm.. i was looking for something that will revert automatically or easily, but looks like saving the state and manually reverting is the only option, as jquery onchange is fired after value has changed.

Comment: selecting an specific chosen when there are many chosen can be done by using 
`$(select#the_class_id).on(......);`

Answer (score 0):

The chosen documentation describes the [Triggered Events](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#triggered-events)

To catch the event on "search-choice-close", you can try the following:

```
 $('#selectID').on('change', function(change, deselected) { //selected OR deselected
    //do something
    console.log('Value Deselected');
  });
```